# Can k-NN be ensembled?

Tags: k-nearest-neighbour, ensemble-learning

Decision trees suffer from high variance. Random Forests were suggested as a way of ensembling DT to solve this problem, and were shown to perform well for several problems.

k-NN are also high bias classifiers, so in theory the same approach could be used with them. But I haven't heard much about ensembles of k-NN learners.

Is there a reason for this? can k-NN be ensembled and if not why?

Answer (score 5):

Sure, k-NN can be ensembled. You could, for example, use resampling to generate different models (like with a Random Forest), or you could vary N, or you could use different functions for computing the distance. But, my experience is that k-NN rarely does well in high dimensional problems, so it would just be an ensemble of bad models, which isn't going to do well relative to an ensemble of good models.

Comment: I assume that you mean varying k, not N?

Comment: Depending on what you mean by 'bad', that may still work.  After all the whole idea of gradient boosting is to take a large number of weak learners and use them as an ensemble.  It's conceivable the same ideas would work with knn.

Comment: Well, by bad I mean that I have never seen a k-NN model outperform a tree or GLM or LDA or anything else for that matter in a real world model with more than a few predictors. No doubt a well tuned k-NN model could do well as a part of an ensemble of other model types, but the question asks about an ensemble of k-NN models, and I was just trying to explain why I wouldn't bother.

Answer (score 3):

I see four abstract ways to do so from simplest to more complex.

- By applying $k$-NN in different Random Projections latent space or other (eg Neural network autoencoder latent space) and combine them.
  that is: $Ensemble(kNN_{raw},kNN_{projected}) $
- apply different colaborative filtering scores eg. average distance, mean distnace, max, or any other linear combination eg: $ score = w_1+d_{k_1} + w_2+d_{k_2} ...$ (for unseuprvised learning only), ann similarly combine them.
- use different bins of neighbors eg the bin_1: 1st-10th k neighbors, bin_2: 10th-20th.
  and combine the score from bin_number $k$-NN.
- different distance definition (minkowski, manhatan etc)
  Hope it helps